# Registro de boletos Caixa WebService SOAP WSDL PHP

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Amigos, nunca trabalhei com WS, mas agora, em decorrência das novas mudanças, estou precisando registrar boletos que gero em um site. Recebi um documento da CEF mas até agora não consegui fazer funcionar.

Seguem as instruções:

URL:
https://barramento.caixa.gov.br/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo

Toda chamada ao Web Service deverá ser realizada por meio de comunicação segura (SSL/HTTPS) e em método POST. 
Recomendamos a utilização das mensagens XSD e WSDL fornecidos pela CAIXA para construção da solução, prezando o correto ordenamento dos campos.

Abaixo, a própria Caixa fornece uma ideia de como deve ser o resultado do xml:
O exemplo abaixo demonstra o envio de dados gerados pelo cliente à CAIXA, referente à entrada de uma solicitação de registro de título.

```
<ns3:SERVICO_ENTRADA  xmlns:ns2="http://caixa.gov.br/sibar" xmlns:ns4="http://caixa.gov.br/sibar/manutencao_cobranca_bancaria/boleto/externo"> <ns2:HEADER> <VERSAO>1.0</VERSAO> <AUTENTICACAO>wIXyzrhD7HjlrpCP1xNnq8vFE7ggAGuz/srw1BOtxDY=</AUTENTICACAO> <OPERACAO>INCLUI_BOLETO</OPERACAO> <SISTEMA_ORIGEM>SIGCB</SISTEMA_ORIGEM> <DATA_HORA>20170221110643</DATA_HORA> </ns2:HEADER> <DADOS> <INCLUI_BOLETO> <CODIGO_BENEFICIARIO>537588</CODIGO_BENEFICIARIO> <TITULO> <NOSSO_NUMERO>14000000091946802</NOSSO_NUMERO> <NUMERO_DOCUMENTO>NF123456</NUMERO_DOCUMENTO> <DATA_VENCIMENTO>2017-02-21</DATA_VENCIMENTO> <VALOR>1.00</VALOR> <TIPO_ESPECIE>99</TIPO_ESPECIE> <FLAG_ACEITE>S</FLAG_ACEITE> <DATA_EMISSAO>2017-02-21</DATA_EMISSAO> <JUROS_MORA> <TIPO>ISENTO</TIPO> <DATA>2017-02-21</DATA> <VALOR>0</VALOR> </JUROS_MORA> <VALOR_ABATIMENTO>0</VALOR_ABATIMENTO> <POS_VENCIMENTO> <ACAO>DEVOLVER</ACAO> <NUMERO_DIAS>0</NUMERO_DIAS> </POS_VENCIMENTO> <CODIGO_MOEDA>9</CODIGO_MOEDA> <PAGADOR> <CPF>00000000191</CPF> <NOME>EXEMPLO DE NOME DO PAGADOR</NOME> <ENDERECO> <LOGRADOURO>SAUS QUADRA 3</LOGRADOURO> <BAIRRO>BRASILIA</BAIRRO> <CIDADE>BRASILIA</CIDADE> <UF>DF</UF> <CEP>70070030</CEP> </ENDERECO> </PAGADOR> 38.239 v002 micro     26 
LEIAUTE DE ARQUIVO ELETRÔNICO - WEBSERVICE XML COBRANÇA BANCÁRIA CAIXA 
<SACADOR_AVALISTA> <CNPJ>00360305000104</CNPJ> <RAZAO_SOCIAL>EXEMPLO DE NOME DO SACADOR AVALISTA</RAZAO_SOCIAL> </SACADOR_AVALISTA> <PAGAMENTO> <QUANTIDADE_PERMITIDA>1</QUANTIDADE_PERMITIDA> <TIPO>NAO_ACEITA_VALOR_DIVERGENTE</TIPO> <VALOR_MINIMO>0.00</VALOR_MINIMO> <VALOR_MAXIMO>0.00</VALOR_MAXIMO> </PAGAMENTO> </TITULO> </INCLUI_BOLETO> </DADOS> </ns3:SERVICO_ENTRADA>
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda para montar os parâmetros de conexão para envio e tratamento do retorno?

Answer (score 0):

Escrevi um protótipo de biblioteca seguindo o exemplo abaixo. [Está disponível aqui](https://github.com/vmassuchetto/WebserviceCaixa).

---

Segue um exemplo para a inclusão de boletos que usa [NuSOAP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) e [XmlDomConstruct](https://github.com/jboesch/FreshBooksRequest-PHP-API/blob/master/lib/XmlDomConstruct.php). Você vai ter que trocar as constantes no meio desse código para as variáveis aplicáveis ao seu ambiente e ao convênio da empresa.

```php
include(LIB_DIR . '/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
include(LIB_DIR . '/XmlDomConstruct/XmlDomConstruct.php');

// Hash de autenticação
$raw = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '',
    '0' . CODIGO_BENEFICIARIO .
    NOSSO_NUMERO .
    strftime('%d%m%Y', strtotime(DATA_VENCIMENTO))) .
    sprintf('%015d', preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', VALOR)) .
    sprintf('%014d', CNPJ));
$autenticacao = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $raw, true));

    $xml_array = array(
        'sibar_base:HEADER' => array(
            'VERSAO' => '1.0',
            'AUTENTICACAO' => $autenticacao,
            'USUARIO_SERVICO' => 'SGCBS02P',
            'OPERACAO' => 'INCLUI_BOLETO',
            'SISTEMA_ORIGEM' => 'SIGCB',
            'UNIDADE' => UNIDADE,
            'IDENTIFICADOR_ORIGEM' => OUT_IP,
            'DATA_HORA' => date('YmdHis'),
            'ID_PROCESSO' => ID_PROCESSO,
        ),
        'DADOS' => array(
            'INCLUI_BOLETO' => array(
                'CODIGO_BENEFICIARIO' => CODIGO_BENEFICIARIO,
                'TITULO' => array(
                    'NOSSO_NUMERO' => NOSSO_NUMERO,
                    'NUMERO_DOCUMENTO' => NUMERO_DOCUMENTO,
                    'DATA_VENCIMENTO' => DATA_VENCIMENTO,
                    'VALOR' => VALOR,
                    'TIPO_ESPECIE' => '99',
                    'FLAG_ACEITE' => 'S',
                    'DATA_EMISSAO' => DATA_EMISSAO,
                    'JUROS_MORA' => array(
                        'TIPO' => 'ISENTO',
                        'VALOR' => '0',
                    ),
                    'VALOR_ABATIMENTO' => '0',
                    'POS_VENCIMENTO' => array(
                        'ACAO' => 'DEVOLVER',
                        'NUMERO_DIAS' => NUMERO_DIAS,
                    ),
                    'CODIGO_MOEDA' => '09',
                    'PAGADOR' => array(
                        'CPF' => sprintf('%014d', CPF),
                        'NOME' => NOME,
                        'ENDERECO' => array(
                            'LOGRADOURO' => LOGRADOURO,
                            'BAIRRO' => BAIRRO,
                            'CIDADE' => CIDADE,
                            'UF' => UF,
                            'CEP' => CEP
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );

    // Geração do XML
    $xml_root = 'manutencaocobrancabancaria:SERVICO_ENTRADA';
    $xml = new XmlDomConstruct('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->fromMixed(array($xml_root => $args));
    $xml_root_item = $xml->getElementsByTagName($xml_root)->item(0);
    $xml_root_item->setAttribute('xmlns:manutencaocobrancabancaria',
        'http://caixa.gov.br/sibar/manutencao_cobranca_bancaria/boleto/externo');
    $xml_root_item->setAttribute('xmlns:sibar_base',
        'http://caixa.gov.br/sibar');
    $xml_string = preg_replace('/^<\?.*\?>/', '', $xml->saveXML());

    // Consulta ao webservice
    $client = new nusoap_client(ENDERECO_WSDL, $wsdl = true, $timeout = TIMEOUT);
    $response = $client->call('INCLUI_BOLETO', $xml_string);
    $err = $client->getError();
    if (!$client->fault && !$err)
        echo $err; // inclusão falhou

    print_r($response) // inclusão feita com sucesso
```