# Inclusão boleto caixa

Tags: xml, web-service

Amigos, estou tentando incluir um boleto no WebService da Caixa, porém, ao utilizar o layout passado na documentação, não tenho sucesso.

**O erro é esse: (500 Internal Server Error)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>The Operation could not be found. The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is: 'https://des.barramento.caixa.gov.br:7081/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo' and the SOAPAction was ''</faultstring><detail><Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The Operation could not be found. The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is: 'https://des.barramento.caixa.gov.br:7081/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo' and the SOAPAction was ''
at com.ibm.broker.axis2.Axis2Invoker.invokeAxis2(Axis2Invoker.java:3123)
at com.ibm.broker.axis2.TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.invokeAxis2(TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.java:664)
at com.ibm.broker.axis2.TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.invokeAxis2(TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.java:610)
```

**O XML para inclusão é esse:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ext="http://caixa.gov.br/sibar/manutencao_cobranca_bancaria/boleto/externo"
xmlns:sib="http://caixa.gov.br/sibar">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ext:SERVICO_ENTRADA>
        <sib:HEADER>
            <VERSAO>1.0</VERSAO>
            <AUTENTICACAO>### REMOVI ###</AUTENTICACAO>
            <USUARIO_SERVICO>SGCBS02P</USUARIO_SERVICO>
            <OPERACAO>INCLUI_BOLETO</OPERACAO>
            <SISTEMA_ORIGEM>SIGCB</SISTEMA_ORIGEM>
            <UNIDADE>0283</UNIDADE>
            <DATA_HORA>20180829110000</DATA_HORA>
        </sib:HEADER>
        <DADOS>
            <INCLUI_BOLETO>
                <CODIGO_BENEFICIARIO>0806248</CODIGO_BENEFICIARIO>
                <TITULO>
                    <NOSSO_NUMERO>0</NOSSO_NUMERO>
                    <NUMERO_DOCUMENTO>00000011</NUMERO_DOCUMENTO>
                    <DATA_VENCIMENTO>2018-09-09</DATA_VENCIMENTO>
                    <VALOR>1000.00</VALOR>
                    <TIPO_ESPECIE>99</TIPO_ESPECIE>
                    <FLAG_ACEITE>S</FLAG_ACEITE>
                    <DATA_EMISSAO>2018-08-29</DATA_EMISSAO>
                    <JUROS_MORA>
                        <TIPO>TAXA_MENSAL</TIPO>
                        <VALOR>2.00</VALOR>
                    </JUROS_MORA>
                    <VALOR_ABATIMENTO>100.00</VALOR_ABATIMENTO>
                    <POS_VENCIMENTO>
                        <ACAO>DEVOLVER</ACAO>
                        <NUMERO_DIAS>999</NUMERO_DIAS>
                    </POS_VENCIMENTO>
                    <CODIGO_MOEDA>9</CODIGO_MOEDA>
                    <PAGADOR>
                        <CPF>22222222222</CPF>
                        <NOME>TESTE PAGADOR 001</NOME>
                        <ENDERECO>
                            <LOGRADOURO>SAUS QUADRA 03</LOGRADOURO>
                            <BAIRRO>BRASILIA</BAIRRO>
                            <CIDADE>BRASILIA</CIDADE>
                            <UF>DF</UF>
                            <CEP>70070030</CEP>
                        </ENDERECO>
                    </PAGADOR>
                    <MULTA>
                        <DATA>2018-09-09</DATA>
                        <VALOR>20.00</VALOR>
                    </MULTA>
                    <DESCONTOS>
                        <!--1 to 3 repetitions:-->
                        <DESCONTO>
                            <DATA>2018-08-30</DATA>
                            <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
                            <PERCENTUAL>10.00</PERCENTUAL>
                        </DESCONTO>
                        <DESCONTO>
                            <DATA>2018-09-02</DATA>
                            <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
                            <PERCENTUAL>5.00</PERCENTUAL>
                        </DESCONTO>
                        <DESCONTO>
                            <DATA>2018-09-05</DATA>
                            <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
                            <PERCENTUAL>3.00</PERCENTUAL>
                        </DESCONTO>
                    </DESCONTOS>
                    <FICHA_COMPENSACAO>
                        <MENSAGENS>
                            <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WEBSERVICE 1</MENSAGEM>
                            <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WEBSERVICE 2</MENSAGEM>
                        </MENSAGENS>
                    </FICHA_COMPENSACAO>
                    <RECIBO_PAGADOR>
                        <MENSAGENS>
                            <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WS MSG PAG 1</MENSAGEM>
                            <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WS MSG PAG 2</MENSAGEM>
                            <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WS MSG PAG 3</MENSAGEM>
                            <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WS MSG PAG 4</MENSAGEM>
                        </MENSAGENS>
                    </RECIBO_PAGADOR>
                    <PAGAMENTO>
                        <QUANTIDADE_PERMITIDA>1</QUANTIDADE_PERMITIDA>
                        <TIPO>ACEITA_VALORES_ENTRE_MINIMO_MAXIMO</TIPO>
                        <VALOR_MINIMO>500.00</VALOR_MINIMO>
                        <VALOR_MAXIMO>1500.00</VALOR_MAXIMO>
                    </PAGAMENTO>
                </TITULO>
            </INCLUI_BOLETO>
        </DADOS>
    </ext:SERVICO_ENTRADA>
</soapenv:Body>
```

**URL da requisição:** 
https://barramento.caixa.gov.br/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo

Alguém tem ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: ,estou tendo o mesmo problema, conseguiu resolver?

Comment: como está fazendo a requisição? programa ou alguma ferramenta?

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu tentei via curl e via PHPStorm, nos dois casos obtive a mesma resposta que o Diego

Comment: @PedroHenrique, na sua chamada tem o `SOAPAction` setado?

Comment: @RicardoPontual minha chamada é igual a do Diego, essa é a chamada de exemplo do manual

Comment: acho que está faltando incluir o `SOAP-Action` na sua chamada. Antes de postar uma solução, precisamos confirmar isso.. veja na mensagem de erro: *"the SOAPAction was ''"* e segundo o manual de LEIAUTE (horrível isso) da caixa: [manual](http://www.caixa.gov.br/Downloads/cobranca-caixa/Manual_Leiaute_Webservice.pdf) o endpoint aceita várias actions, tem que definir, olha só: *"Registro, alteração e baixa de títulos:
https://barramento.caixa.gov.br/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo"*

Comment: precisa definir na action se está fazendo "INCLUI_BOLETO", "ALTERA_BOLETO", "BAIXA_BOLETO", "CONSULTA_BOLETO", que são todas operações no mesmo endpoint

Comment: Questão semelhante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231364/registro-de-boletos-caixa-webservice-soap-wsdl-php

Comment: Consegui!
No cabeçalho, você tem que adicionar a ação do Soap.
No meu caso, estava fazendo inclusão... então, ficou assim:
SOAPAction: "IncluirBoleto"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:
No cabeçalho do envio, adicionei:
`SOAPAction: "IncluirBoleto"`
Funcionou 100%, me retornou `200 OK` na resposta.

Boa sorte!

Comment: mas Diego, foi o que te sugeri nos comentários né? *"acho que está faltando incluir o SOAP-Action na sua chamada. Antes de postar uma solução, precisamos confirmar isso.."*

Comment: Exatamente! Tava na correria e não li todos os comentários, dei um ^ no seu comentário. 
Respondi minha pergunta pra quem entrar e já ver uma resposta correta. 
Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: ok, mas quando alguém resolve o problema normalmente a gente posta uma resposta e aceita a resposta da pessoa, mas bom pra vc ter resolvido

Comment: Eu já tinha resolvido antes de ver teu comentário, mas mesmo assim muito obrigado, e pra ser resposta tem que responder como RESPOSTA e não como comentário. Grande abraço.